# class method not getting detected inside target of threading module

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, oop, python-multithreading

`Threading`
I'm currently working on a mini TCP GUI chat room project. the problem i encountered is with guiloop function though i have defined it still the target function parameter throws an error saying threading.Thread(target=guiloop, args=(self,)).start()
NameError: name 'guiloop' is not defined please help me
thank you

```
    import tkinter
    import threading
    import socket
    
    import tkinter.scrolledtext
    from tkinter import simpledialog
    
    
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 9080
    
    class Client:
        def __init__(self,host,port):
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.connect((host,port))
    
            msg = tkinter.Tk()
            msg.withdraw()
    
            self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname",parent = msg)
    
            
    
        def guiloop(self):
            self.win = tkinter.TK()
            self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")
            self.chat.label.config(font=("Ariel",12))
            self.chat_label.pack(padx=20,pady=5)
    
            self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
            self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
            self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
    
            self.msg_label = tkinter.label(self.win, text= "Message:",bg = "lightgray")
            self.msg_label.config(font = ("Ariel",12))
            self.msg_label.pack(padx =20, pady=5)
    
            self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win,height = 3)
            self.input_area.pack(padx=20,pady=5)
    
    
            self.button_send = tkinter.Button(self.win, text = "send", command = self.write)
            self.button_send.config(font = ("Ariel",12))
            self.button_send.pack(padx=20,pady=5)
            self.gui_done  = True
    
    
            self.win.mainloop()
    
            self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.stop)
    
    
    
        def write(self):
            message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
            self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            self.input_area.delete('1.0','end')
    
        def stop(self):
            self.running = False
            self.win.destroy()
            self.sock.close()
            exit(0)
    
    
        def recieve(self):
            while self.running:
                try:
                    message = self.sock.recv(1024)
                    
                    if message =='NICK':
                        self.sock.send(nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                    else:
                        if self.gui_done:
                            self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                            self.text_area.insert('end',message)
                            self.text_area.yview('end')
    
                except ConnectionAbortedError:
                    break
                except :
                    print("Error")
                    self.sock.close()
                    break
        def run(self):
            self.gui_done = False
            self.running = True
    
            threading.Thread(target=guiloop, args=(self,)).start()
            recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=recieve)
    
            recieve_thread.start()
    client = Client(HOST,PORT)
    client.run()
```

Comment: Have you tried `target=self.guiloop` with no args?

Comment: Additionally, `recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=recieve)` should be `recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recieve)`, `self.win = tkinter.TK()` should be  `self.win = tkinter.Tk()` and `self.chat` is never created before  it is referenced.